# Copying of files from dependant war file is not working on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, build.gradle

We have common resources in a separate war file, common-web.war, which are shared accross  war files in multiple applications. THe resources are copied using from - into construct as 
below. THe issue is that files are copied in to destination war file when build is run locally. HOwever the copying of files is not working on Jenkins.

```
    configurations {
       commonWebResources {
           description = "common web resources"
       }
    }

    dependencies {

        runtime commonWebResources( group: 'com.xxx.common.framework', name: 'common-web', version:'1.0.4-SNAPSHOT')

    }


    war {
        archiveName = 'xxx-web.war'
        from (zipTree(configurations.commonWebResources.singleFile)) {
            exclude '*/web.xml'
            exclude '**/config/app/*.xml'
        }
        into("/")
    }
```

Comment: What is not working? Run gradle in *debug* mode, `-d`, and verify the output.

Comment: copying of files is not working on Jenkins. I ran with debug mode but could not get enough information

Comment: @JohnLiva did u get any solution